# How to interact with element underneath?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I come across a problem that I can't interacte with elements which fully covered by other elements recently. Here below is the code:

```js
  

  
var data = [ [40, "blue"], [80, "red"] ];

var g = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
  .attr({
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
  })
  .style("border", "1px solid #ccc")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)");

g.selectAll("circle").data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    r: function(d){ return d[0]; },
    fill: function(d){ return d[1]; },
    "fill-opacity": 0.5
  })
  .on("mouseenter", onMouseEnter)
  .on("mouseleave", onMouseLeave)
  .on("mousemove",  onMouseMove)
  .on("mouseover",  onMouseOver)
  .on("mouseout",   onMouseOut);

function onMouseEnter(d){
  console.log(d[1] + ": Mouse Enter");
}
function onMouseLeave(d){
  console.log(d[1] + ": Mouse Leave");
}
function onMouseMove(d){
  console.log(d[1] + ": Mouse Move");
}
function onMouseOver(d){
  console.log(d[1] + ": Mouse Over");
}
function onMouseOut(d){
  console.log(d[1] + ": Mouse Out");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

[image]

No matter which mouse events delegated on the blue circle, you can't receive any responds, just because it is fully covered by the big red circle.

Finally I get an idea that delegating a mousemove event on "g" element(circles' parent node) and dectecting which circle is the closest one, then do something. So my question is that is there any smart way to interate with the elements underneath?

Comment: Do you need any mouse event for the bigger circle?

Comment: Yes, I need interact with all circles which including the red ones.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I am sorry for this. As you can see I am a newbie to stackoverflow, and I am not a English native speaker. I did not vote your comments instantly, trust me I did it lately.

Comment: @1Cr18Ni9 -- If an answer works for you, you need to [select it as your accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).  This provides feedback to others visiting this post, and provides credit to the answerer.  If you get a reputation as a person who fails to select answers, you will find that the community may become reluctant to provide answers to your questions.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Now I get it. I never notice that, many thanks!

Comment: @1Cr18Ni9 Good on you. Deleting my comments.